# How can to keep a Python script running on the web server/hosting?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Recently I started working with python and found a cool script to monitor the changes of a website minute after minute and then send an email to one or more people if the content matches what I'm looking for. I know there are better ways to make it, but so far it's working great and i'll share it in case some of you may need:

```
# Import requests (to download the page)
import requests

# Import BeautifulSoup (to parse what we download)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Import Time (to add a delay between the times the scape runs)
import time

# Import smtplib (to allow us to email)
import smtplib


# This is a pretty simple script. The script downloads the homepage of VentureBeat, and if it finds some text, emails me.
# If it does not find some text, it waits 60 seconds and downloads the homepage again.

# while this is true (it is true by default),
while True:
    # set the url as you please,
    url = "google.com"
    # set the headers like we are a browser,
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ Safari/537.36'}
    # download the homepage
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    # parse the downloaded homepage and grab all text, then,
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    
    # if the number of times the word "Google" occurs on the page is less than 1,
    if (str(soup).find("Google") == -1):
        # wait 60 seconds,
        time.sleep(60)
        # continue with the script,
        continue
        
    # but if the word "Google" occurs any other number of times,
    else:
      #print(soup)
      # create an email message with just a subject line,
      msg = 'Subject: A prefeitura de Ilhabela postou um edital novo, VAI LA VER!'
      # set the 'from' address,
      fromaddr = 'testmail@gmail.com'
      # set the 'to' addresses,
      toaddrs  = ['anothertestmail@gmail.com']
      
      # setup the email server,
      server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
      server.starttls()
      # add my account login name and password,
      server.login('tesmail@gmail.com', 'TheTest')
      
      # Print the email's contents
      print('From: ' + fromaddr)
      print('To: ' + str(toaddrs))
      print('Message: ' + msg)
      
      # send the email
      server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
      # disconnect from the server
      server.quit()
      
      break
```

Now I wonder: how can I keep this scrip running 24/7? Google and Amazon probably have solutions for this, but I'm too unexperienced to find the answers. Could you guys help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can run it on your own computer using Task Scheduler if you're using Windows.

Comment: This is my plan B. I need something on cloud, where the service will be always up and running.

Comment: or crontab in Linux if you use Linux VPS.